# Typescript: why i getting error, when describe object in interface with [id: string]: any?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Code:

```
interface Interface {
  [id: string]: Interface2;
}

interface Interface2 {
  [id: string]: string|boolean;
}

var a:Interface = {
  abc: {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
  },
  cde: {
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd',
    e: true
  }
};

if (a.cde.e) {
  console.log(1);
} else {
  console.log(2);
}

if (a['cde']['e']) {
  console.log(1);
} else {
  console.log(2);
}
```

At the bottom, you can see two conditions.

On first condition, compiler gives me an error:
`Property 'cde' does not exist on type 'Interface'.`

On the second condition - no error.

Why compiler complain at first condition?
How i can fix that?

You can try here www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `[id: string]: Interface2;` as `Dictionary`. Dictionary keeps data and keys also are part of the data. In order to have strongly typed interface and be able to access it's properties you can add properties directly to interface:

```
interface Interface3 {
  abc: Interface2;
  cde: Interface2;
}
```

In all other cases you will use dynamic properties, like using `any` type:

```
var c: any = a;
if (c.cde.e) {
  console.log(1);
}
```

or using bracket notation

```
a['cde']['e']
```

Answer (score -1):

It throws a compile error when you try to access `a.cde.e` via dot notation because the interfaces represent index types.

Index types expect you to provide an index using bracket notation—not dot notation.

To get it to work, you could instead use an implicit type that represents your object:

```
var a = {
  abc: {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
  },
  cde: {
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd',
    e: true
  }
};

a.cde.e; // ok
```

**Or** represent your object exactly in an interface.

This might not work in your actual scenario, so if you really need to use an index type the only option without asserting to the `any` type is to use bracket notation—`a["cde"]["e"]`. Don't use the `any` type because then you lose type safety.